# Search MySql Database & view Result

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have already upload a simple php registration form (Details are below) & it works perfect. But now I want to create a search box so that my students can verify their registration using "Registration Number". [Exp: http://www.nbceindia.in/student-verification.php ]
Can anybody help me by creating the code for me.

Thanks in advance.

Details:

**1. entry.php**

```
<!DOCTTYPE html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"></head>
<title>Registration</title>
<body>  

<form name="form1" method="post" action="register_ac.php">

    <li>Registration No.<input type="text" name="registration" class="#" id="registration" maxlength="8"/></li>
    <li>First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" class="#" id="firstname"/></li>
    <li>Surname<input type="text" name="surname" class="#" id="surname"/></li>
    <li>Course Code<input type="text" name="course" class="#" iid="course" maxlength="7"/></li>
    <li>Duration (Months)<input type="text" name="duration" class="#"  id="duration"/></li>
    <li>Mobile<input type="text" name="mobile" class="#" id="mobile" maxlength="10"/></li>
    <li>Addressline1<input type="text" name="addressline1" class="#" id="addressline1"/></li>
    <li>Addressline2<input type="text" name="addressline2" class="#" id="addressline2"/></li>
    <li>City<input type="text" name="city" class="#" id="city"/></li>
    <li>Postcode<input type="text" name="postcode" class="#"  id="postcode" maxlength="6"/></li>


    <input type="submit" id="textarea" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**2. register_ac.php**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="username"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="database_name"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table_name"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form
$registration=$_POST['registration'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$course=$_POST['course'];
$duration=$_POST['duration'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$addressline1=$_POST['addressline1'];
$addressline2=$_POST['addressline2'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(registration, firstname, surname, course, duration, mobile, addressline1, addressline2, city, postcode)
VALUES('$registration', '$firstname','$surname','$course','$duration','$mobile','$addressline1','$addressline2','$city','$postcode')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Sure - here's the verification code! `2a82a7042f264309859e585c4102a7a6`

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just the scenario create a html form make in it textbox that sends for example registration to a php file ,that file gets the text and within that file write query that searches that text in the database using select statement then make output inside table like this

search.html
    {

```
<li>ID.<input type="text" name="id" class="#" id="id" maxlength="8"/></li>


<input type="submit" id="textarea" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
</form>
}


disp.php{
<?php

$id1=$_GET['id'];
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
if(!$con){
die('<h1>Could not connected '. mysql_error().'<br>');
}
$sqlStmt="SELECT * FROM table_name  WHERE Id='$id1'";

mysql_select_db('db_name');

$res=mysql_query($sqlStmt,$con);
?>
<table border="1" bgcolor="cyan">
<tr bgcolor="yellow">
    <th>Id</th> <th>FirstName</th> <th>LastName</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($user=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $user['Id'];?></td>    
    <td><?php echo $user['First name'];?></td>    
    <td><?php echo $user['sur name'];?></td>    

</tr>    
<?php        
}    
?>    
</table>    


?>

}
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working:

Result is : 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ../search.php on line 19
----------------
For details in line 19 the code is :
    <?php
    while($user=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    ?>

Comment: please if you use this as it is ,not working but follow only the steps and do it in your own database table and columns

Comment: please help, as i have very little knowledge about php.

Now the code is running but in the table onl;y labels are coming no data is showing. Only ?> sign is visible. Please help

My registration id is in the first column. I want to searh by registration id only.